# PHP: Echo something for each 2 results

Tags: php, loops, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a simple foreach loop that outputs the information I want.

However, I want to wrap it with a div for every two results.
I tried the modulus operator with no success (the result applied for every result).

So, my code:

```
foreach ($result->data as $info) {

    // A open div to wrap two results
    echo 'something';
    // An closing div to wrap the previous two results
}
```

Comment: the idea of using the modulus operator sounds reasonable. how did you use it? show your (not working) try

Comment: Put a `for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)` inside your `foreach` or count it with just `for`. Did I miss something? Because I can't see "modulus" point in this.

Comment: Modulus makes it very easy without an extra nested loop.

Comment: @AndrewCoder I agree with you, I saw your answer now. But it won't enclose the results properly when it has more than two of them, because you opened the div before the loop. `div` opening and closing should also be part of the loop, just inside a different scope.

Comment: Yes I did.  This is how I do this type of operation.  (Moreso with tables).
Works just fine in my use cases.  There are other ways to do it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it!

```
foreach ($result->data as $i=>$info) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) echo '<div>';
    echo $info;
    if ($i % 2 == 1) echo '</div>';
}
if (count($result->data) % 2 == 1) echo '</div>';
```

exactly what you asked ;)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Sejzer worked like a charm! Clear and consise!

Answer (score 0):

add an index count then check that its divisible by two in the code.
IN THIS CASE the if block needs to be at the top of the foreach loop, since I started $i at 0.  Please stop editing that portion :)

```
$i = 0;
// Create first new div before loop, here.
echo '<div>';    //first div
foreach ($result->data as $info) {

    // An closing div to wrap the previous two results
    if ($i % 2){
        // Code here would occur after each two iterations
        // IE: close div then open new one. something like this
        echo '</div><div>';
    }

    // A open div to wrap two results
    echo 'something';

    $i++;
}
// close final div after loop, here.
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Your solution almost worked despite that the first and the last divs are enclosing with one element only.

Comment: I don't see that being the case.  The loop would be on it's third iteration before the close of first div and open on second.  As long as the total items are divisible by 2, it should output properly... alternatively one extra item would be in a div on its own at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way: Iterate in steps of 2.

```
for ($cc = 0; $cc<count($result->data); $cc += 2) {
    // here >> start div container for both
    echo $result->data[$cc];
    if (defined($result->data[$cc+1])) 
         echo $result->data[$cc+1];
    // here >> end div container for both
}
```

HTML omitted for clearness.

You can also add an else branch to output a placeholder if the result contains an odd number of items.

Answer (score 0):

For outputting every two results from array you can also use

```
<?php

$array = range( 1, 20 );

foreach( array_chunk( $array, 2 ) as $pair ) {
  echo '<div>' , implode( ' ', $pair ) , '</div>';
}

// <div>1 2</div>
// <div>3 4</div>
// etc

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

set 2 variables, string and int
save the value in string variable if the value of the int variable is not even
when the second variable is an even number
wrap in div

Answer (score -1):

//just simply

```
<?php 
   foreach($result->data as $i=>$info){
     if($i<5){
        echo $info
}
}          
 ?>
```